# Store multiple files in a single file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm building a presentation tool with Vue, like PowerPoint, where users can create slides with different content, for example videos and images.

Now I'd like users to be able to save the presentation as one single file, with all the content files embedded (jpg/mp4/etc.).

Is it possible to create such a "container file" from the browser?

And when the user loads this file I'd like to use these files in my HTML, for example by using `<video src="file:///example.mp4">`.

I could of course save all files as eg. base64 in a single file, but since especially videos can be rather large files it would be nice if the file(s) don't have to be loaded into the RAM but can be accessible from the harddisk (as a stream?).

Comment: LibreOffice for example uses a format similar to ZIP files storing all relevant information, AFAIK. Since you tagged your question as Electron-related, what about ASAR? Take a look at [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/electron/asar) and let me know if that's a viable solution so I can post an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Yes ZIP or ASAR would be nice! Is it possible to stream for example a video file from such an archive into an HTML `<video>`, or an image file into an `<img>` tag?

Comment: It should be possible using Electron and ASAR files, since ultimately your packaged app is read from an ASAR file by Electron and Electron's `fs` module should have the appropriate capabilities. I'd just try it out with a simple test archive...